# how to use d3 .ticks to show original y-axis values in bar chart

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have some number of amount (in dollar) which I am showing on y-axis and year on x-axis. now, I want to show original number on y-axis but not able to do.

i mean on y axis i want to show number from 1 to 100000 as amount but now, with .ticks(10) i can only used between 0 to 8000 amount at y axis.

and one more thing that if i want to show name as string at x axis then how can i show please let me know. i am stuck here and newly with d3.

```
function test() {

var graph_data;

// in graph_data it should contain value like this 
//  [Object { letter="2011", frequency="10000"}, 
//  Object { letter="2012", frequency="8200"}]

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, 110], .3);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .tickPadding(10)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .tickPadding(3)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(10);

var svg = d3.select("#award_by_year_chart").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  x.domain(graph_data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(graph_data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);

   svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Total dollar");

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(graph_data)
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); });

  function type(d) {
    d.frequency = +d.frequency;
    return d;
  }
 }
```

now, this code is working as below chart image. and i want to change value of y axis according to total dollar value and  it's coming from table and it can also -ve as well +ve and upper limit not fixed. then how can resolve.

[image]

please give me valuable solution.

thanks

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do. From your code, it looks like you're currently displaying numbers on the y axis and strings on the x axis. Is your question how to format the numbers with a dollar sign and how to parse the strings into dates?

Comment: Hi Lars Kotthoff ... 
actually as per my above code on x axis amout value is displaying

Comment: i have modified my question and add image for more clarification. please check.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it -- does the picture show what you currently have or waht you're trying to do? Also, it seems that your total value is negative?

Comment: actually .... this image is showing according to my above code. it can also take negative value. now, if i pass value 20000 as total amount then at x axis. maximum range should display 8000 then bar should cross at upper side but i want to set in between. 
if you can then let me know at my skype manijain333

Comment: Do you want to set the [`.domain()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#wiki-linear_domain)?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, from what I understand from your question here's what I got:

> i mean on y axis i want to show number from 1 to 100000 as amount but
>   now, with .ticks(10) i can only used between 0 to 8000 amount at y
>   axis.

For this I would check out https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-tickValues, which documents the function `tickValues`. With this you can specify exactly what you want to show on the y axis. Say you want to show just 0 and 100000 then you can simply pass the array [0, 10000].

> and one more thing that if i want to show name as string at x axis
>   then how can i show please let me know. i am stuck here and newly with
>   d3.

```
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);
    .selectAll('text')
    .text(function(d) {
        return 'Some string: ' + d.letter
     })
```

This will let you customize any of the tick values on the x axis. In case I didn't understand the first part of the question, you can also use this trick on the y axis to customize the output of the tick value.

Comment: thnx this was helpful but if y axis value (total dollar) is negative then which kind of bar chart you prefer.. i means how to customize or have any other example there.

Comment: You can always reverse the bar chart so the bar seems like it's going downward (put the x axis on the top and reverse the y domain). This way the negative values make more sense. I'm not sure if that's what you mean though.